# Symfony 3 session query blocking with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, symfony

I have a somewhat large (but not ridiculously so) site running under Symfony 3, using PDO sessions with PostgreSQL 9.5 as the database. We occasionally run into a deadlock situation in the database that appears to be the result of session handling, with the session update and garbage collection queries interacting with each other in such a way that the processes stop completing.

For example, the following PostgreSQL query (which looks at granted locks and what is waiting on them):

```
SELECT bl.pid                 AS blocked_pid,
       a.usename              AS blocked_user,
       ka.query               AS blocking_statement,
       now() - ka.query_start AS blocking_duration,
       kl.pid                 AS blocking_pid,
       ka.usename             AS blocking_user,
       a.query                AS blocked_statement,
       now() - a.query_start  AS blocked_duration
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks         bl
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity a  ON a.pid = bl.pid
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         kl ON kl.transactionid = bl.transactionid AND kl.pid != bl.pid
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity ka ON ka.pid = kl.pid
 WHERE NOT bl.granted;
```

May produce a result such as this:

```
 blocked_pid | blocked_user |                                        blocking_statement                                         | blocking_duration | blocking_pid | blocking_user |                                         blocked_statement                                         | blocked_duration 
-------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------
        5549 | example      | SELECT session_data, session_lifetime, session_time FROM session WHERE session_id = $1 FOR UPDATE | 00:37:04.217044   |        17009 | example       | SELECT session_data, session_lifetime, session_time FROM session WHERE session_id = $1 FOR UPDATE | 00:18:16.18061
       18016 | example      | SELECT session_data, session_lifetime, session_time FROM session WHERE session_id = $1 FOR UPDATE | 00:37:04.217044   |        17009 | example       | SELECT session_data, session_lifetime, session_time FROM session WHERE session_id = $1 FOR UPDATE | 00:35:57.814924
       14582 | example      | SELECT session_data, session_lifetime, session_time FROM session WHERE session_id = $1 FOR UPDATE | 00:37:04.217044   |        17009 | example       | DELETE FROM session WHERE session_lifetime + session_time < $1                                    | 00:39:28.512274
       26589 | example      | SELECT session_data, session_lifetime, session_time FROM session WHERE session_id = $1 FOR UPDATE | 00:37:04.217044   |        17009 | example       | SELECT session_data, session_lifetime, session_time FROM session WHERE session_id = $1 FOR UPDATE | 00:28:41.270193
        5549 | example      | DELETE FROM session WHERE session_lifetime + session_time < $1                                    | 00:39:28.512274   |        14582 | example       | SELECT session_data, session_lifetime, session_time FROM session WHERE session_id = $1 FOR UPDATE | 00:18:16.18061
       18016 | example      | DELETE FROM session WHERE session_lifetime + session_time < $1                                    | 00:39:28.512274   |        14582 | example       | SELECT session_data, session_lifetime, session_time FROM session WHERE session_id = $1 FOR UPDATE | 00:35:57.814924
```

I don't think we are doing anything non-standard with Symfony in this case, and our databases are working fine otherwise. Our session configuration in Symfony's `config.yml` is as so:

```
pdo:
    class: PDO
    arguments:
        dsn: 'pgsql:dbname=%database_name%;host=%database_host%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
    calls:
        - [setAttribute, [3, 2]] # \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
example.session_storage:
    class: Example\PlatformBundle\Security\ExampleSessionStorage
    arguments: [ '%session.storage.options%', '@session.handler', '@session.storage.metadata_bag', '@request_stack' ]
session.handler.pdo:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
    arguments: [ '@pdo', '%pdo.db_options%' ]
```

The only custom code we have in that `ExampleSessionStorage` class is to change the cookie domain due to some custom handling we need, which is why the request stack is being injected. I don't see how that could be affecting this.

This one has stumped me and I am not sure where to look for answers. Could this be something to do with Symfony PDO configuration on locking for updates? Perhaps there is a related database setting we are missing?